# Google Chrome Plays Sound when Page Doesn't Have Anything

Tags: google-chrome, audio

I am having a very odd problem with Google Chrome. It keeps muting itself on WIndows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, but when I unmute it, you can hear bits and pieces of a commercial playing. I just did it now, and I heard part of a Geico commercial playing. It seems to come and go randomly, and it started happening only after two programs were installed without my consent. These are 'TidyNetwork' and 'Re-markit'. They randomly show advertisements in your web browser. I was unable to remove them using traditional methods, so I found their source files in the `Program Files` folder, and deleted them. Although the video that usually came with the ads doesn't show anymore, I suspect that somehow the sound is still there. Is this possible? How can I stop this from happening? I am trying to make a video demonstrating this strange problem, but I am having a hard time getting my screencast software working when I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved. Apparently when the virus was installed, it added an update service to my Windows startup that regenerated all of the files, resulting in my deletion being useless. I installed the trial of Malwarebytes PRO, and it kept blocking me from some I.P. address that Chrome was trying to connect to. I noticed that with this connection blocked, Chrome wasn't acting funny anymore. I used my trial of Malwarebytes to clean my computer, and it worked. I was so happy with what Malwarebytes had done for me, that I just bought it now!